# Euclidean distances determine the points uniquely

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I saw a conclusion: If we fix an arbitrary set of $n+1$ affine independent points $\{p_0,p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ in $\Bbb R^n$, then the Euclidean distances $\{|x-p_j|\}_{j=0}^n$ determine the points $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ uniquely.

I have no idea of proving the above conclusion.

Comment: Hint: For any assigned values of the set of radii $r_0,r_1,...,r_n$, what does the solution set of $|x-p_j|=r_j$ look like? And how many points can be in the intersection of those solutions sets as $j$ varies from $0$ to $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For two distinct points $x$, $x'$, the set of points $p$ such that $|p-x|=|p-x'|$ forms a hyperplane (perpendicular to $xx'$, through the middle of it), so it cannot contain $n+1$ affine independent points $p_1$, $\ldots$, $p_{n+1}$.

$\bf{Added:}$ This will not be true for other normed spaces. For instance, take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\|(x_1, x_2)\| = \sqrt[4]{x_1^4 + x_2^4}$. Consider the points $x=(-1,1)$, $x'=(1,2)$.  The equal distance curve is not a line, so we can find three non-collinear points on it. [[image: equal distance curve1]

Comment: You mean $p_ip_j=p_im+mp_j$?

Comment: @mathbeginner: yes, we use this vector equality :-)

Comment: If we consider the space is a normed space, can we prove it similarly?

Comment: @mathbeginner: It does not work for some normed spaces.  For instance on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|(x_1, x_2)\|= \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$, we can take the points $(0,1)$, $(1,2),(2,4)$, and $x=(10,0)$, $x'=(10,1)$  ( the first component does all the work in this instance).  Would be interesting the case of a strictly convex norm

Comment: It is not true for other normed spaces. The idea is: consider a two dimensional normed space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $\|\cdot \|_p$ norm,  $1<p < \infty$.   Take two distinct points $x$, $x'$ and look at the set $\{p \ | \ |p-x| = |p-x'| \}$.  In general this will be a curve, but not a line.  So we can find three non-collinear points on this curve..

Comment: I noticed that you changed the answer. I don't understand why it forms a hyperplane ($M$ is a hyperplane if its codimenion is 1) and why a hyperplane connot cotain $n+1$ independent points

Comment: $px = px'$ is equivalent to : $pm$ perpendicular to $x x'$, so $p$ lies on the hyperplane perpendicular to $xx'$ and through $m$ ( $m$ -- the middle of $xx'$).   $k$ affine independent points means they are not contained in an affine subspace of dimension $k-2$.   (for instance : $3$ affine independent points means $3$ points not on a line).